# Add custom advanced rules for merge method on Pull Requests

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api, pull-request

I have the following branch structure:

```
base
  base-tenant1 - > master-tenant1
  base-tenant2 - > master-tenant2
```

The goal is to make it so that:
In the first place, all PRs that go to base have to be done with Squash & Merge (easily done - using branch protection rules)

But here it gets tricky: I need all PRs that go into `base-tenantX` that come from either the `base` branch or a branch that matches a determined regex (let's say `base-to-tenant*`), need to be normal merges (block Squash and Merge), and all other PRs that go into `base-tenantX` MUST be Squashed.

Furthermore, the same needs to apply for PRs that go from `base-tenantX` into `master-tenantX`

Is there any way to make these "smarter" checks on PR merge methods in Github?

Thanks for any help!

I have tried playing around with branch protection rules, but it's not possible to do something like this. I was thinging into either adding certain labels automatically that would force a certain merge method, because the labels could be added in a github action, but I'm not quite sure whether this is the right way to go